# CSS child/nth child/typeof selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I can't figure how to select element in CSS.

```
<div class="text">
    <img src="./img1.jpg">
    <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<br> 
<div class="text">
    <img src="./img2.jpg">
    <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

How do I select every second image in the text div? I want for 1st one to float left, and for the second to float right. Whatever I try they are both floating left. As I can understand odd selector, just selects both of them.

```
img:nth-of-type(even){
float: right;
}
img:nth-of-type(odd){
float: left;
}
```

My goal is this: [image]

Comment: Reusing IDs like `id="text"` is _invalid_. Did you mean to address the `<div>`s with your `:nth-of-type` selector? Using it on `img` doesn’t make sense here.

Comment: okay, that was just for example, i use <article> tag?

The goal I want to achieve is float 1st image to left, and 2nd img to right;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Select the correct container (not image)**

Firstly, the images are all floating to the left because every image is the first of type in its container. What you really want the image in every odd/even *div* to float to the left/right:

```
.text:nth-of-type(even) img{ float: right; }
.text:nth-of-type(odd) img{ float: left; }
```

2. **Use clearfix to stack the containers correctly**

You also need to clear your floats for the divs to stack properly. You can do this using the clearfix solution on the container of the floating elements, e.g.

```
.text:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
/* alternate the display between odd & even containers */
.text:nth-of-type(even) img{
float: right;
}
.text:nth-of-type(odd) img{
float: left;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* clearfix to make each container fully contain its floated elements */
.text:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* for testing so we can see where image would be */
img { height:100px; width:100px;  background: #ccc;}
.text { background:#eee;}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <img src="./img1.jpg">
    <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <img src="./img2.jpg">
    <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

And of course don't use the same id, as everyone has been pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

First, `id` is an unique identificator and should be used only once per page. You'd better change it to `class`. And `<br>` tag is unnecesary in this example, you can style any margins with css:

```
<div class="text">
  <img src="./img1.jpg">
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <img src="./img2.jpg">
  <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

Then, images inside every odd and even blocks can be styled as:

```
.text:nth-child(even) > img {
  float: left;
}
.text:nth-child(odd) > img {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean `.text` instead of `.class` in your `.class:nth-child`

Comment: yeah, sorry there was a typo

Comment: as I can understand '>' selects immediate children, if image wouldn't be immediate one and further down bellow, would I have to use + selector tag?#Thanks for help, it works in this case, and I will try to implement it in website

Comment: not necessary - use space instead : `.text:nth-child(even) img { ... }`

Comment: better practice is to add `class="image"` to the img tag and target it as `.text:nth-child(even) .image { ... }`

Comment: thanks, I did not know the correct syntax for nth-child and I figured that it is not possible to add something after the brackets.!